# « Remettre en place », « rétablir » ou « restaurer »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Si les mesures d’urgence venaient à être

…remises en place, qu’adviendrait-il de ton restaurant nouvellement ouvert ?

…rétablies, qu’adviendrait-il de ton restaurant nouvellement ouvert ?

…restaurées, qu’adviendrait-il de ton restaurant nouvellement ouvert ?

N’hésitez pas à tourner différemment et plus élégamment les phrases ci-haut.

Si les autorités annonçaient le retour des mesures d’urgence, qu’adviendrait-il de ton restaurant ouvert depuis peu ?

Si le gouvernement annonçait le retour des mesures d’urgence, qu’adviendrait-il de ton restaurant ouvert récemment ?

Comment: "revemper" trahit vos racines, chère amie. :)

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa We say frappé for the milk-shake drink, and Thérèse and I have established a relationship over the course of her questions. The comment was not unkind at all. There is nothing wrong with asking people what their native language is. It can often help to decipher what they mean.

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa When I "meet people" for the first time out in the world, we don't discuss language, translation and uses. This site is very specific. **She might very well be writing an advanced writing style book and looking to check it or improve it**. which would be pretty cool.

Comment: de ton restaurant rouvert dernièrement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Si on reconfine, tu fais quoi de ton resto tout neuf ?